# wildfly 10 custom login module with client-cert auth not executing

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, client-certificates, wildfly-10

I need to run a custom-login (I really do need a custom implementation) module alongside with client-cert auth on wildfly 10, but the module itself never executes. The same approach was working on a jboss 6.

My custom module:

```
public class WsLoginModule implements LoginModule {

@Override
public void initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map<String, ?> sharedState,
        Map<String, ?> options) {
  System.out.println("initialize()");
}

@Override
public boolean login() throws LoginException {
    System.out.println("login()");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean commit() throws LoginException {
    System.out.println("commit()");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean abort() throws LoginException {
    System.out.println("abort()");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean logout() throws LoginException {
    System.out.println("logout()");
    return true;
}

}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>action</web-resource-name>
        <description>constraint</description>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>myapp</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description>no description</description>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
    <realm-name>custom-security-domain</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description></description>
    <role-name>myapp</role-name>
</security-role>
```

jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_6_0.xsd" version="6.0">
<security-domain>custom-security-domain</security-domain>
```

On standalone.xml, included the ssl cert config:

```
        <security-realm name="SslRealm">
            <server-identities>
                <ssl>
                    <keystore path="/home/me/keystore.javaks" keystore-password="passwd"/>
                </ssl>
            </server-identities>
        </security-realm>
```

also, my custom-security-domain on standalone.xml

```
            <security-domain name="custom-security-domain" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="my.app.WsLoginModule" flag="required"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

even changed the default-security-domain

```
<default-security-domain value="custom-security-domain"/>
```

and finally, https-listener

```
<https-listener name="default-ssl" security-realm="SslRealm" socket-binding="https"/>
```

Everything seems to be ok as showed above, but then i get only "Forbidden" when trying to execute simple tasks as invoking a webservice (even when presenting a certificate). The weird thing here is that my class "WsLoginModule" never ever gets executed.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code of the login module in a JBoss module. Follow the documentation on how to do this, many examples exist for database JDBC drivers.